# Labels for BE properties in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my BE class I have certain properties to match with table fields. I want to expose descriptive name for each of these properties. for example to show it as column header in grid.

For example, there is a property called `FirstName`. I want to expose it's descriptive name as `First Name`

For this, I have created an array of pairs as a property of this BE class. i.e, `myarray("FirstName","First Name")`
Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this useful and this is how I solved it. I'm posting this since it might be useful for others.

in BE define this.

```
[DisplayName("First Name"), Description("First Name of the Member")]
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set { _firstName = value; }
}
```

You can read these details of each property as below;

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection propertiesCol = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(objectBE);

PropertyDescriptor property;

for (int i = 0; i < propertiesCol.Count; i++)
{
    property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(objectBE)[i];

    /*
    // Access the Property Name, Display Name and Description as follows
    property.Name          // Returns "FirstName"
    property.DisplayName   // Returns "First Name"
    property.Description   // Returns "First Name of the Member"
    */
}
```

- where `objectBE` is the object instance of BE class.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in your model:

```
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

And then in your View you can reference the label name like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.FirstName)
```

Comment: `DisplayFor` will display `FirstName` value (using default or predefined template), not the *name* of the property. You probably mean `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m=>m.FirstName)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[DisplayName("First name")]` attribute on your BE property.

And then in view use:
`@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.FirstName)`

Similar question here on SO: [How to change the display name for LabelFor in razor in mvc3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651254/how-to-change-the-display-name-for-labelfor-in-razor-in-mvc3)

**EDIT**

You can also use the `[Display(Name="First name")]` attribute on all of your BE properties.
Then create a template for displaying your BE (more info how to create template here: [How do I create a MVC Razor template for DisplayFor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710140/how-do-i-create-a-mvc3-razor-template-for-displayfor)).

And then in the view you would simply use:

`@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m, "MyModelTemplateName")`